# JavaScript split a string

Tags: javascript, split

Please see my JavaScript code:

```
var str = "/price  -a 20 tips   for model";
var removeSlsh = str.slice(1); //output = price  -a 20 tips   for model
var newStr = removeSlsh.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim().split(' ');
console.log(newStr); // Output = ["price", "-a", "20", "tips", "for", "model"]
```

Above code working fine. Every string split which has space. But I need to split above string like

```
1 = price  // Field name
2 = -a     // price type -a anonymous, -m model, -p private
3 = 20     // amount of price
4 = tips for model  //comment
```

Output should be

```
["price", "-a", "20", "tips for model"]
```

**EDIT:**

If i set limit of the split text. It looks like

```
var newStr = removeSlsh.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim().split(' ',4);
console.log(newStr); // Output = ["price", "-a", "20", "tips"]
```

N.B - Price type and comments are optional field. string may be `/price 20` or `/price 20 tips for model` or `/price -a 20` but price field is mandatory and must be a numeric value. Second field is optional it you will not entering any value. If you will entering any text except `-a, -m, -p` then this field validate.

Comment: someone asked the similar problem. What you need is split them into array and join the last few items using " "

Comment: If your first 3 parameters are always *fieldname*, *flag* and *value* you could just split out the rest of the array and use *.join(' ')* on it to extract the message. If you have more formats, we'd need some more information.

Comment: How to join last few item? this is dynamic. I don't know comment is coming or not. comment is a optional field.

Comment: /PRICE OR /TIP - Come ON!!!????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to *split*, but to *extract parts*, which can be done with a regular expression:

```
var parts = str.match(/^\/(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s*(.*)/).slice(1);
```

Result:

```
["price", "-a", "20", "tips   for model"]
```

Now suppose that

1. the string you get might be wrong,
2. you want to ensure the third part is a number,
3. the parameter -a or -e or -something is optional,
4. the last part (the comments) is optional,

then you may use this:

```
var m = str.match(/^\/(\S+)(\s+-\w+)?\s+(-?\d+\.?\d*)\s*(.*)/);
if (m) {
    // OK
    var parts = m.slice(1); // do you really need this array ?
    var fieldName = m[1]; // example: "price"
    var priceType = m[2]; // example: "-a" or undefined
    var price = +m[3];    // example: -23.41
    va comments = m[4];   // example: "some comments"
    ...
} else {
   // NOT OK
}
```

Examples:

- `"/price -20 some comments"` gives `["price", undefined, "-20", "some comments"]`
- `"/price -a 33.12"` gives `["price", "-a", "33.12", ""]`

Comment: But price type is optional.

Comment: how do you know the exact format of str?? the one he has mentioned is just an example!
But nice one, really liked the regular expression!

Comment: your regex definitely works there is no doubt abt it! but without him mentioning any conditions how can you be sure of it!

Comment: This is working fine but this case is showing wrong output `/price 20 sending USD 20 to dystroy :)`

Comment: @chatfun I didn't knew the second argument (like -a) was optional

Comment: Yes second `-a` is optional and also this is a mandatory while i will entering any letter except `-a, -m, -p` on that place.

Comment: I have edited my question. Your answer approximately right. But i am getting undefined value when i left second field.

Comment: If i left second field my output should be come `["price", "-20", "some comments"]`

Comment: @chatfun Why ? This make you lose the fact there was no parameter. You might remove it easily with `parts = parts.filter(Boolean)` but you probably should keep it. In such a case it's also usually better to directly name fields (see edit).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76959/discussion-between-chatfun-and-dystroy).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "/price  -a 20 tips   for model";
str = str.replace(/\//g,'').replace(/\s+/g,' '); //removes / and multiple spaces
var myregexp = /(.*?) (.*?) (.*?) (.*)/mg; // the regex 
var match = myregexp.exec(str).slice(1); // execute the regex and slice the first match
alert(match)
```

---

Output:

```
 ["price", "-a", "20", "tips for model"]
```

Comment: `/price 20 good morning Pedro Lobito` its not giving proper result. Check this.

Comment: good morning @chatfun, I guess you'll have to update you're answer with several examples you need to match.